# What is the difference between placing layout inside a FrameLayout root or making the layout as a root without using a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-framelayout

In the following link: [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) it is written:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

From the way i understand this quote, it means that it is recommended to add only one child to **FrameLayout**  (although it possible to use more than one in order to make each view to overlap his "brother"). **But**, i can't understand the use of the **FrameLayout** only with one child, Let's say a *LinearLayout*. What is the difference between starting a layout file with a *LinearLayout* as the root of the  xml file (see code 1), or wrapping it with a **FrameLayout** as the root, and then placing a *LinearLayout* has is son that will be the father of many other ViewGroup and View (see code 2)?

Code 2:

```
<FrameLayout
...>
    <LinearLayout
     ...>
       <ImageView .... />
       <TextView .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

code 1:

```
<LinearLayout...>
   <ImageView.../>
   <TextView.../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A `FrameLayout` as a parent for just a single `View` is usually only useful when you need a placeholder container; e.g., for `Fragment`s, or some other content that will be inserted at runtime. In a known, prefab layout – like in your first block – it's useless, and is just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Mike M., Thanks!